# Convert smart plant .vue model to FBX

Tags: 3d, format, fbx, format-conversion

Our customer wants to convert a smart 3D model in .vue format to other common formats such as fbx or obj. We are aware that there are some tools available, such as Smart Review and Navisworks, that can perform this conversion. However, we are looking for a direct method to transfer the model without using these tools.

We have tried several ways to analyze the .vue file, but have not been successful. We are seeking a solution to directly convert .vue to fbx. This will enable us to use the model in a variety of applications. We suspect that the .vue format is a binary file, so any solution must be able to handle this format.